# How to find elements with attr id after click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, var, attr

Basically, I'm working with three tabs called 'Monday', 'Tuesday' and 'Favorites'. I have a toggle icon which is an empty heart at start => ('.favorite i') within each box. If I'm in Monday and click on the icon the empty heart turns to be filled out and the parent is cloned and added to the '#fav' tab.

When clicking in the heart within the cloned div the whole box gets removed from '#fav' tab but the icon within the original div doesn't get empty and keeps filled out.

So I thought the only way to do this was to grab the id from the original and cloned div which is the same and change the toggle class from there.

Any help is appreciated!

I've created this fiddle to give a better overview of the issue:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/itsfranhere/nbLLc3L0/44/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="tabs_main">

      <div class="col-md-5"><a data-target="#mon" class="btn active" data-toggle="tab">Monday</a></div>
      <div class="col-md-5"><a data-target="#tue" class="btn active" data-toggle="tab">Tuesday</a></div>
      <div class="col-md-2"><a data-target="#fav" class="btn active" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>

   </div>

   <div class="tab-content">

     <div class="tab-pane active" id="mon">
       <br>
       <div class="spaces">
         <div class="box-container">
           <div class="box not-selected" id="box1">
           <a href="#" class="favorite"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
         </div>
         <div class="box-container">
           <div class="box not-selected" id="box1">
           <a href="#" class="favorite"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="tab-pane" id="tue">
       <br>
       <div class="spaces">
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="tab-pane" id="fav">
        <br>
     </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// Clones
$('div.tab-pane').on('click', '.favorite', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var par = $(this).parents('.box');

  var id = $(this).parents('.parent');
  var idFind = id.attr("id");
  var idComplete = ('#' + idFind);
  console.log(idComplete);

  //TOGGLE FONT AWESOME ON CLICK
  if ($(par).hasClass('selected')) {
    par.find('.favorite i').toggleClass('fa-heart fa-heart-o');
  } else {
    par.find('.favorite i').toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart');
  };

  if ($(par.hasClass('selected')) && ($('i').hasClass('fa-heart-o'))) {
    par.closest('.selected').remove();
    var getIcon = $(this).find('.favorite i').toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart');
  }

  // Clone div
  var add = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
  add.each(function(){

    if ($(add.find('.not-selected .favorite i').hasClass('fa-heart'))) {

      var boxContent = $(add).clone(true, true);
      var showHide = $(boxContent).find(".session").addClass('selected').removeClass('not-selected');
      var get = $(boxContent).html();

      var temp = localStorage.getItem('sessions');

      var tempArray = [];

      tempArray.push(get);

      var myJSONString = JSON.stringify(tempArray);

      var parseString = $.parseJSON(myJSONString);

      var finalString = myJSONString.replace(/\r?\\n/g, '').replace(/\\/g, '').replace(/^\[(.+)\]$/,'$1').replace (/(^")|("$)/g, '');

      var myJSONString = localStorage.setItem('sessions', finalString);

      $("#fav").append(tempArray);

    };

  });

});
```

What I've tried..

```
  var id = $(this).parents('.parent');
  var idFind = id.attr("id");
  var idComplete = ('#' + idFind);

  if ($(par.hasClass('selected')) && ($('i').hasClass('fa-heart-o'))) {
    par.closest('.selected').remove();
    var getIcon = $(idComplete).find('.favorite i').toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart');
  }
```

Comment: Looks like all you really need is `$(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart');`

Comment: What is that .favorite in your on second argument?

Comment: Why do you need the ID? If you're getting the element to get its ID, you already have the element. So it would just be `$(this).parents(".parent").find(".favorite i").toggleClass...`

Comment: In the end, you're asking how to perform DOM selection, but we don't know what your DOM looks like, nor what you're selecting and from where.

Comment: Thank your for your response. I've updated the question @spanky

Comment: I've updated the question, sorry if I wasn't clear enough @adeneo